# AngleSharp: properly setting Accept-Lang header

Tags: .net, .net-core, globalization, anglesharp

I'm using [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) to query **google.com**. All results I get are crearly produced for an **it-IT** locale (since I execute the code from *Italy*). A test using a browser set to **en-US** proofs it.

From a discussion in *GitHub issues* of the project, I learned that I was setting the `Accept-Language` header in the proper way.

This code confirms it:

```
var formatter = new PrettyMarkupFormatter();
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.812");
var requester = new HttpClientRequester(client);
var config = Configuration.Default.WithRequester(requester).WithDefaultLoader();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await context.OpenAsync("http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php");
var table = document.QuerySelector("table.standard");
Console.WriteLine(table.ToHtml(formatter));
```

How **google.com** (or a web server in general) can recognize the client locale in a different way? And how to properly set a given locale in **AngleSharp**?

Making light about it, will be very appreciated and more over I think it's an important thing to understand in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google gets the locale from your location / region, which is given by the IP address.

You can override this setting via the Google cookie (or by setting it on the page, which will trigger the cookie). The cookies with the NID values are the ones to be respected.

> Most Google users will have a preferences cookie called ‘NID’ in their browsers. A browser sends this cookie with requests to Google’s sites. The NID cookie contains a unique ID Google uses to remember your preferences and other information, such as your preferred language (e.g. English), how many search results you wish to have shown per page (e.g. 10 or 20), and whether or not you wish to have Google’s SafeSearch filter turned on.

See https://policies.google.com/technologies/types?hl=en-US.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer, @Florian Rappl! Thanks for support me also here.,, Since things don't happen for magic, I was wondering about the mechanism. I knew router was involved but with this all detailed info, you saved me a lot of time. Moreover this help me think over if allowing the override of router locale makes sense in my library.